# Does Next.js have equivalent auto-register feature like Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, next.js, nuxt.js

**Background story (you can skip to question)**

As a begginer (full-stack, but about 8 years behind) I'm struggling with deciding what to learn.

**Vue** and **Nuxt.js** are great to understand, but as a designer, I really miss the option to use **Framer Motion.** Also the fact that I can't use **Tailwind UI** (Headless UI) with **Nuxt** (as of right now) since Nuxt still uses **Vue 2.**

As I worked on my app I felt that I would have much better online support with React, specifically with **Next.js** to make the learning curve easier. The overall community is bigger and there are much more tutorials. But I discovered that Nuxt used some things that Next is missing (probably?) — **like auto registering components.**

---

**The question:**

I really miss not caring about **writing an import path** to each component I use.
**Nuxt.js** did this **automatically**. **Is there something similar in Nuxt.js?**

I could also nest them in subfolders like this:

```
/components/Point/Section/Table/Row.vue
```

and put them in code like: `<PointSectionTableRow />`

Comment: `pages` are imported automatically. What happens in pages is up to you. You can reexport existing component there without wrapping it. React requires to import a component that you use because it's closer to vanilla JS than Vue, automatically making them globals them would be a footgun. IDE handles autoimport for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Estus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask) for the comment that IDE's handle autoimport. I discovered [VS Code Auto import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) plugin that can autoimport components, icons etc with just a tooltip click. Very handy!